# Get href and play sound - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my code does not work at all, and I do not know why. What I want from this program is pretty simple - i click at `<a>` tag which has some specific `href` and according this `href` value **sound** will be played.

HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="windows-1250">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <a href="#00"><div class="box">00</div></a>
    <a href="#01"><div class="box">01</div></a>
    <a href="#02"><div class="box">02</div></a>
    <a href="#03"><div class="box">03</div></a>
    <a href="#04"><div class="box">04</div></a>
    <a href="#05"><div class="box">05</div></a>

    <script src="javs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </body>
</html>
```

And javascript looks like this

```
var hrefsound = "";
$(".box").click(function () {
var bhref = $(this).attr("href");
console.log(bhref);
switch (bhref) {
case "#00":
hrefsound = new Audio("http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-      content/uploads/2017/01/seno_02_doprdele_prace.mp3");
    hrefsound.play();
    break;
case "#01":
    hrefsound = new Audio("http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/seno_03_coura.mp3");
    hrefsound.play();
    break;
case "#02":
    hrefsound = new Audio("http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/seno_04_hajzle.mp3");
    hrefsound.play();
    break;
case "#03":
   hrefsound = new Audio("http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/seno_05_smejd.mp3");
    hrefsound.play();
    break;
case "#04":
    hrefsound = new Audio("http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/seno_06_dobytku.mp3");
    hrefsound.play();
    break;
case "#05":
    hrefsound = new Audio("http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/seno_07_se_pobleju.mp3");
    hrefsound.play();
    break;

}
});
```

I am using `jquery` and this should work like this. I also put some **`console.log`** there and href's are set as a undefined - anyone knows why? :-(

Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are handling the click of the `div` elements and attempting to work with the `href` attributes from the `a` elements that contain them. However, it's actually attempting to get the `href` attribute of the `div` that got clicked. Of course, `div` elements, don't have `href` attributes, which is why you are getting `undefined`.

Change your code to attach the click handler to the `a` elements:

```
$("a[href]").click(function () {
```

Of course, that selector will pick up all `<a>` elements, so you could create a class just for these:

```
$(".sound").click(function () {
```

Unless you are doing something else with those `div` elements, there is no need for them at all.

Here's the working code:

```js
var hrefsound = "";
// You want the sounds to play based on the href of the <a> that was clicked
// so set up the click event handler on the <a> - The <div> elements are not required.
$(".sound").click(function () {
  var bhref = $(this).attr("href");
  console.log(bhref);
  switch (bhref) {
    case "#00":
      hrefsound = new Audio("http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/seno_02_doprdele_prace.mp3");
      hrefsound.play();
      break;
    case "#01":
      hrefsound = new Audio("http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/seno_03_coura.mp3");
      hrefsound.play();
      break;
    case "#02":
      hrefsound = new Audio("http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/seno_04_hajzle.mp3");
      hrefsound.play();
      break;
    case "#03":
      hrefsound = new Audio("http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/seno_05_smejd.mp3");
      hrefsound.play();
      break;
  case "#04":
        hrefsound = new Audio("http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/seno_06_dobytku.mp3");
      hrefsound.play();
      break;
    case "#05":
      hrefsound = new Audio("http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/seno_07_se_pobleju.mp3");
      hrefsound.play();
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#00" class="sound">00</a>
<a href="#01" class="sound">01</a>
<a href="#02" class="sound">02</a>
<a href="#03" class="sound">03</a>
<a href="#04" class="sound">04</a>
<a href="#05" class="sound">05</a>
```